# iOS push notification not received even though Azure push notification telemetry says 'Success'

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Here's the result of the Azure push notification telemetry:

```
<ApnsOutcomeCounts><Outcome><Name>Success</Name><Count>1</Count></Outcome></ApnsOutcomeCounts>
```

My certificates are up to date and the app has all of the notification permissions granted. I went through Apple's documentation on [troubleshooting push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG22) and it was useless. How do I troubleshoot further?

Comment: Try some 3rd party like pusher to send push on your device if its working there with your push certificate than you need to check your azure code.

Answer (score 0):

`<Name>Success</Name>` with a `<Count>` greater than 0 means, Azure has **success**fully transmitted this notification to Apple. It does **not** mean, Apple has sent the notification to the device.